# Minecraft [GRADLE] 1.7.2 - Cannot use external .jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm using the apache library httpcomponents in my mod.
So I have 7 jar files, that I've added in my buildpath on Eclipse.

Then compile with eclipse works. When I launch my mod with eclipse it works.

But when I use gradle build command, the custom buildpath isn't considered.

I see I must modify the build.gradle file. I've tried ...

Code:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT'
    compile files('lib/httpcomponents-client/commons-codec-1.6.jar')
    compile files('lib/httpcomponents-client/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar')
    compile files('lib/httpcomponents-client/fluent-hc-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('lib/httpcomponents-client/httpclient-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('lib/httpcomponents-client/httpclient-cache-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('lib/httpcomponents-client/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('lib/httpcomponents-client/httpmime-4.3.3.jar')
}
```

But it doesn't work:

`"Could not find method compile() for arguments [file collection] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@76454e71."`

And I've tried to use the code:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT'
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'lib/httpcomponents-client', include: '*.jar')
}
```

but I've an error too, "Could not find method runtime() for arguments [directory 'lib/httpcomponents-client'] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@40211960."

Could you help me please?
Thanks, and sorry for my bad english :/

isador34

Answer (score 2):

You added the dependencies in the wrong place. They need to go into `dependencies { ... }`, not into `buildscript { dependencies { ... } }`. The former is used for declaring dependencies of your code, the latter for declaring dependencies of the build itself (e.g. Gradle plugins).

PS: It would be easier to resolve these dependencies from Maven Central.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're working off of the [ForgeGradle github repo](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/ForgeGradle). If so, I'm also assuming you're modifying their [build.gradle](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/ForgeGradle/blob/master/build.gradle) file. You might try declaring your dependencies in a similar way. For example, instead of

```
 compile files('lib/httpcomponents-client/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
```

try

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-core:4.3.2'
```

Gradle should pick these up from Maven Central (since the `repositories { }` block declares `mavenCentral()` at the end).

You can track down each of your dependencies by searching for it on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/).

Comment: @user3601775 Was this before or after removing `classpath`? Either way, you might try getting your dependencies from Maven Central, as @peter suggests.

Comment: it's before, I delete all dependencies or apache's dependencies??

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the end of `build.gradle` to include your dependencies in the compilation:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
    // etc
}
```

To build a 'fat jar' containing the classes for all your dependencies, instead add:

```
configurations {
    external
    compile.extendsFrom external
}

dependencies {
    external 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3'
    external 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
    // etc
}

jar {
    from { configurations.external.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

But beware, mods using `org.apache` JARs will still not work, due to a bug in FML: https://github.com/MinecraftForge/FML/issues/424